# Google's Geocode API returns a weird response (binary?)

Tags: api, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to get response from this API call:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=rua+silva+jardim+1161+santa+luzia+mg&language=pt-br&sensor=false

At browser site the response is ok. But when I use this method:

```
private static string GetResultString(string geocodingUrlApi)
  {
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(geocodingUrlApi);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    webRequest.UserAgent = "WayMoto 1.0";

    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

    string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return response;
  }
```

Content method parameter geocodingUrlApi:
[image: Content of geocodingUrlApi]

Content of response var:
[image: Content of response]

thanks for any help.

Comment: looks like a character encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned datatype is a json object (not a string) : application/json.

Here's an article from Microsoft for C# in deserializing json objects returned in a REST API call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

Comment: Even removing the contentType, I have the same behavior, and I do not belive if that was the problem, since I do not want to deserialize the response at that time. What I want to is get the response as string.